# What is the most memory-friendly way to save a large file in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node script that uses the `fs.writeFileSync()` method to write a ~50MB of JSON to a file on disk.

It works fine on my powerful laptop, but when I run it in a cloud VM with 1GB RAM, it crashes with error 137, which seems to indicate excessive memory usage.

Is there a more memory-friendly way to save a file to disk?

This is the error I get:

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 137
```

Comment: Where is this file coming from? You should stream it to disk, instead of writing it all by once (and reading everything into memory)

Comment: @tkausl In my script, I have a large object variable (i.e., JavaScript object) I stringify, and write to disk.

Comment: Are you sure it's the write operation? I can't imagine why this operation would need memory at all.

Comment: @jabaa Yes, I have a log statement before and after the call to `fs.writeFileSync()` and only the "before" statement is logged.

Comment: How much memory does the application consume before the write operation? How much free memory does the system have? Yes, of course it needs memory. It has to stringify the object and that should cost around 50 MB. Do you have less than 50 MB free memory? You could enable swapping but it's slow

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice library called [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) which allows you to stream your data set to e.g. a file, instead of serializing it with `JSON.stringify` and thus not consuming a lot of memory. Something like this should work:

```
const JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
const fs = require('fs');

const records = [
    {id: 1, name: "SomeName123"},
    {id: 2, name: "SomeName123"},
    {id: 3, name: "SomeName123"},
    {id: 4, name: "SomeName123"},
    {id: 5, name: "SomeName123"}
    // a lot more records
];


const transformStream = JSONStream.stringify();
const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/result.json");

transformStream.pipe(outputStream);

records.forEach(transformStream.write);

transformStream.end();

outputStream.on(
    "finish",
    () => {
        console.log("Done");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the wrong question. The right question was "how do I avoid my script crashing without upgrading my RAM?".

The answer is by using a swap file in my Linux server to work around the limited memory. I was not using a swap file, so my RAM was quickly exhausted, but I solved my problem by adding a 2GB swap file. No new code needed.

https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/adding-and-managing-ubuntu-swap-space/

Comment: Depending on the context of how your node-app is running, I'd argue that this is a "better solution"... E.g. if your current code is run inside a node express-app handler, you're blocking all other incoming requests until `JSON.stringify` has finished.

Comment: My code isn't blocking, and the performance doesn't really matter (whether the script takes 2 minutes or 10 minutes isn't a big deal). So the swapfile fixes the problem of memory running out.

Comment: As I said - it depends on the context. And it's definitely not a "memory-friendly" solution, but glad you got it working :)